# How to spread/sync cookies between sites with different top level domains (eg, xxx.uk, xxx.fr, etc)?

Tags: cookies, subdomain, setcookie, tld

We are building an e-commercial site and before now we only maintain a single domain like example.com. For better user experience, we are going to deploy our sites for different countries and setup different top level domains (eg, example.uk, example.fr, etc) for each site. Since we have several cookies used in our site including user_id token for identifying user and tracking id from promotion link (for advertising purpose), how can we sync/spread those cookies for all these sites?

For example, if I have a short promotion link: `http://adexample.com/abc123`, which links to a specific product page (ie, `http://example.uk/items/123789.htm`.) Since the service that processes `http://example.com/abc123` can only `Set-Cookie` to domain `example.com`, **how can we sync the cookie to domain `example.uk`?** What would be the best practice?

Comment: Generally this is often done by using a single host to "store" cookies, like `common.example.com`,  and all others use it.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Yes, the data associated with the cookie will be stored under the cookie of the main site, ie, example.com. My question is how should I spread/sync the cookies to the othre domains so that the other sites can access the data.